# Расчет Line of Sight в географической системе между двумя точками

Tags: c++, геолокация

Существует ли библиотека для расчета `Line of Sight (LOS)` между двумя точками на карте, указывая координаты, на C++? Есть ли данный способ в `GeographicLib`? Искал, не нашел.

Может у кого есть сразу пример как это посчитать?

Comment: А что она должна считать? Видно/не видно?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, те указывается long, lat и alt обоих точек, и должна расчитывать, видно/не видно вторую точку.